# PHP including file only for admin

Tags: php, include, admin

My site consists of a single page (or well, allmost), with on top all handling of `POST` and stuff. Now, I have certain `POST`-things that are solely for admins. These are located in a separate file, so I include it like following:

```
if($_SESSION['type'] == 'admin'){
    include('adminhandler.php');
}
```

Now, in the `adminhandler.php` I also check in each `POST` or function whether the type of the user is correct, for example:

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteUser']) && $_SESSION['type'] == 'admin'){ /* do stuff;*/ }
```

Now, I'm wondering if this is indeed necessary. Is there any chance a user can manipulate anything to somehow include a php file without having a `$_SESSION['type']` of `admin`?

This is probably a silly question, but for security I'd rather take the certain before uncertainty.

Comment: $_SESSION data is kept purely server side. as long as you don't do something stupid like allowing `$_SESSION[$_GET['key']] = $_GET['value']` and let a user DIRECTLY manipulate or influence the session contents, then no... they couldn't get your system to include that file.

Comment: So the second check, inside the checked included file is not necessary?

Comment: Never hurts to have redundant security checking. You might be having a bad hair day sometime and forget to put the checks in the parent file, but if there's a duplicate check inside the included file you'll still be safe.

Comment: I guess I'll just put one extra check around the whole page then, just in case I'd also forget checking every single `POST` or other function ;) Thanks! Insecurity makes my productivity drop significantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by [Marc B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118068/marc-b) (see comments on question), it is advised to do a second check just in case I should forget it.